# jQuery: Simple way to slideToggle multiply elements independently (and similar questions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firstly, I need to say that I'm pretty new to jQuery. 
 
I have this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/dVf8m/ 
I've been wondering if there is a way to do the slideToggle simplier. Now I have two ids on menu elements (`#trigger1` and `#trigger2`) and two ids on the hidden divs (`#one` and `#two`). This also results in double jQuery. Is it possible to avoid all the ids and make it simpler?
Another thing is that if I click on both menu elements (First and Second) both divs appear. I want only one of the hidden divs to be visible at one time? How can I force the first div to disappear when the other one is appearing?
Also, if I'd want to use fadeIn/fadeOut in this situation, how to do it when both of them use the .click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to something like below. Have a class for the div and add click listener to it. add any attribute to the div and give the id of the div to be toggled.

```
<div id="top">
    <ul>
      <li><span id="trigger1" class="toggler" data-item="item1">First</span></li>
      <li><span id="trigger2" class="toggler" data-item="item2">Second</span></li>
      <li>Third</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="item1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Smthn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Smthn2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Smthn3</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="item2">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.toggler').click(function(e) {            
            $("#"+$(this).attr("data-item")).slideToggle(500); 
        });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dVf8m/1/)